# How to create signer hash for cardano-cli transaction build --required-signer-hash?

Tags: cardano-cli

I need to use `--required-signer-hash` instead of `--required-signer` because I don't want to have access to the payment signing key, instead I want a user to create a hash and send it to us. How to create the hash of the payment signing key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command gives the hash of a payment address

```
cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key-file payment.vkey
```

Remember to change the file name from *payment.vkey*